# Law of a Markov process uniquely determined by its 2-dimensional distributions

Tags: probability, markov-process, filtrations

I am stuck with the following problem about Markov processes:

> Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}, \mathcal{F}_t)$ be a filtered probability space. If $X,Y:\mathbb{R}_{+}\times\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ are Markov processes (with respect to $\mathcal{F}_t)$ with the same 2-dimensional distributions, then they are equivalent (they have the same law).

What I want to prove is that they have the same $n$-dimensional distributions for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, i.e. that for all $0\leq t_1 < \dots < t_n \in \mathbb{R},$ and for all $ B_{t_1},\dots, B_{t_n}\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),$ the property $\mathbb{P}(X_{t_n}\in B_{t_n}, \dots, X_{t_1}\in B_{t_1})=\mathbb{P}(Y_{t_n}\in B_{t_n}, \dots , Y_{t_1}\in B_{t_1})$ holds true.

Well, now by induction 
\begin{align}
&\mathbb{P}(X_{t_n}\in B_{t_n}, \dots, X_{t_1}\in B_{t_1})=\\ 
& =\mathbb{P}(X_{t_n}\in B_{t_n}|X_{t_{n-1}}\in B_{t_{n-1}}, \dots, X_{t_1}\in B_{t_1})\mathbb{P}(X_{t_{n-1}}\in B_{t_{n-1}}, \dots, X_{t_1}\in B_{t_1})= \\ 
& =\dots= \\
& =\mathbb{P}(X_{t_n}\in B_{t_n}|X_{t_{n-1}}\in B_{t_{n-1}}, \dots, X_{t_1}\in B_{t_1})\dots \mathbb{P}(X_{t_2}\in B_{t_2}|X_{t_1}\in B_{t_1})\mathbb{P}(X_{t_1}\in B_{t_1}).
\end{align}
By Markov property I can obtain that 
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(X_{t_n}\in B_{t_n}|X_{t_{n-1}})=\mathbb{P}(X_{t_n}\in B_{t_n}|X_{t_{n-1}},\dots,X_{t_1})= \mathbb{P}(X_{t_n}\in B_{t_n}|\mathcal{F}_{t_{n-1}}),
\end{equation} and this should tell me that every factor in the expression above is determined by the 2-dimensional distribution (e.g. $\mathbb{P}(X_{t_n}\in B_{t_n}|X_{t_{n-1}}\in B_{t_{n-1}} \dots, X_{t_1}\in B_{t_1})=\mathbb{P}(X_{t_n}\in B_{t_n}|X_{t_{n-1}}\in B_{t_{n-1}})$), but sadly I can't formalize the passage from the conditional probability (which is defined as a random variable) in the Markov property to the conditional probability that appears in the final statement.

The question thus boils down to:
**Is the following property true? Why?**
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(X_{t_n}\in B_{t_n}|X_{t_{n-1}},\dots,X_{t_1})=\mathbb{P}(X_{t_n}\in B_{t_n}|X_{t_{n-1}}) \implies \\ \mathbb{P}(X_{t_n}\in B_{t_n}|X_{t_{n-1}}\in B_{t_{n-1}} \dots, X_{t_1}\in B_{t_1})=\mathbb{P}(X_{t_n}\in B_{t_n}|X_{t_{n-1}}\in B_{t_{n-1}})
\end{equation}
From a symbolic point of view it seems reasonable, but I can't connect the two concepts.
This should also help me to get some intuition about the conditional probability (as a random variable). Thanks to everybody.

Comment: Wouldn't this follow immediately from the fact $X$ and $Y$ have the same semigroup? You can use the semigroup to construct the fdds.

Comment: Which semigroups? How would I have to use it? Isn't there a more straightforward way from what I came to?

Comment: The semigroup associated with a Markov process. Just google it if you want to know more. Chapter 7 of the book of Schilling and Partzsch is quite accessible and explains this topic very well. I don't know if there is an easier way. But maybe you could start with three dimensional fdds first and try to generalize from that.

Comment: Ok I've got some notes about it, but sorry if I'm insistent, is it impossible to continue from what I came to?

Comment: I honestly don't know. I haven't tried solving it your way.

Comment: @RiccardoCeccon what book is this? What page is the exercise?

Comment: It's from my teacher's exercise paper, do you want the link? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement that the Markov property implies
$$ \mathbb{P}(X_{t_n} \in B_{t_n} | X_{t_{n-1}} \in B_{t_{n-1}}, \dots, X_{t_1} \in B_{t_1}) = \mathbb{P}(X_{t_n} \in B_{t_n} | X_{t_{n-1}} \in B_{t_{n-1}}) $$
is hopelessly false, as the example $B_{t_{n-1}} = \mathbb{R}$ will show. The Markov property does not say anything about a *window* of space. The statement appearing in the Markov property regarding the conditioning on $X_t$ can be stated in terms of regular conditional probabilities as a property holding for all $X_t=x_t$. This is why it is useful to think not about the measure $\mathbb{P}$, but the *family* of measures $\mathbb{P}_x$, indexed by elements $x$ in your state space. In particular, the probability of a collection of paths $\{X_t, t\geq 0\}$ under $\mathbb{P}_x$ is nonzero only if there are paths in the collection such that $X_0 = x$.

For a more direct counterexample, consider the discrete time Markov chain $\{X_i, i\geq 0\}$ defined on $\{0, 1\}$, with transition kernel 
$$ p(0, 1) = 1, \quad p(1, 0) = 1. $$
Thus, the chain is deterministic and goes to $1$ from $0$ and vice-versa. Let $\mu = (1/2, 1/2)$ be the initial distribution of $X_0$. The entire path of $\{X_i, i \geq 0\}$ is determined by $X_0 = x_0$. The above statement does not hold for $t_i = i$, since
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{2}&= & \mathbb{P}_\mu(X_2 \in \{1\} | X_1 \in \{0, 1 \}) \\
&\neq & \mathbb{P}_\mu(X_2 \in \{1\} | X_1 \in \{0, 1\}, X_0 \in \{0 \}) \\
&= & 0.
\end{eqnarray*}

As to your question, you don't need to use semigroups (as hinted in the comments). It depends on what your definition of "equivalent" is, and how you construct a Markov process in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the counterexamples! I found them really clarifying, especially the last one! By equivalent I mean having the same n-dimensional distributions for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, which should be the same as having the same law in the space $(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}_{+}},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})^{\mathbb{R}_{+}}).$ So let me ask just one more question: what should my approach to the problem be? Thanks for everything.

Comment: Be careful about $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R^+}$. If you endow it with the $\sigma$-algebra generated by all cylinder sets (which is maybe what you mean by $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})^{\mathbb{R}_+})$, then $C([0, \infty))$ is not a measurable subset of this $\sigma$-algebra. (This is because you cannot specify uncountably many points via countable intersections and complements, which would be needed to enforce continuity.) Returning to the question, is the Markov process in question time-homogeneous?

Comment: If the Markov process is time-homogeneous, then for any $B \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $t\geq 0$, $E_x[1_B(X_t) | \mathcal{F}_s] = E_x[1_B(X_{t-s})]$. Then, for any $B_i$, $t_1 < \dots < t_n$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
E_x[\prod_{i=1}^n 1_{B_i}(X_{t_i})] &=& E_x[E_x[\prod_i 1_{B_i}(X_{t_i}) | \mathcal{F}_{t_{n-1}}]] \\
&=& E_x[\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} 1_{B_i}(X_{t_i}) P_{X_{t_{n-1}}}(X_{{t_n} - t_{n-1}} \in B_n)],
\end{eqnarray*}
where in the last step we used time-homogeneity and the Markov property. The random variable $P_X(X_t \in B)$ is to be interpreted as $\phi(X)$, where $\phi(x) = P_x(X_t\in B)$.

Comment: I believe the above is correct, but as with all things related to conditional expectation and the Markov property, it requires a clear mind and at least three checks. Indeed, at least one line is wrong:
$$ E_x[1_B(X_t)|\mathcal{F}_s] = E_{X_s}[1_B(X_{t-s})]. $$

Comment: Ok, it makes sense to me. Unfortunately I did not have time- homogeneity as hypothesis, but I don’t really want to ask you other efforts, so thanks a lot!